# How to make an update windows 10 PS Script to resume after restart and update a CSV file with the result?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, windows-update

I'm still new to scripting/programing so I'm sorry if its a dumb question in advance.
I'm trying to build a script that will install all updates that are older than 2 weeks (the exact time is less relevant) and then will create a CSV file with the results of the update.

I've encountered 2 issues:

1. I'm failing to create the final CSV file
2. I'm wondering what is the best practice to keep PS script running after restart and let it check if there are another updates to update.
   I read that using Registry key is better than using Task schedule but to be honest I still hesitate a lot to mess with the Registry, there is another good practice that I'm not familiar with?

Create Update Results CSV part:

```
$WUHistory = Get-WUHistory -MaxDate (Get-Date).adddays(-10) | Sort-Object -Property 
ComputerName,OperationName,Result,Date,Title

$RecentUpdatesString = @{}
$UpdateCount = 0
ForEach ($U in $NeedUpdate){
    ForEach($T in $WUHistory) {
        If($WUTitle -like "*$U*"){
            Write-Host "Contain [$U]"
            If (!($WUHistory[$UpdateCount] -in $RecentUpdatesString)){
                $RecentUpdatesString += $WUHistory[$UpdateCount]
            }
        }
    }
    $UpdateCount += 1
    Write-Host "Count = $UpdateCount"
}
$RecentUpdatesList = ($RecentUpdatesString | Out-String).Trim() 


#Create CSV file for Recent Updates
$RecentUpdatesPath = "C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\Documents\RecentUpdates.csv"
if(!(Test-Path $RecentUpdatesPath)){
    New-Item -Path $RecentUpdatesPath -Value $RecentUpdatesList
}
else{
    Remove-Item -Path $RecentUpdatesPath
    New-Item -Path $RecentUpdatesPath -Value $RecentUpdatesList
}

$RecentUpdatesCSV = Import-Csv -Path $RecentUpdatesPath
```

NeedUpdate = list of all updates ID that need to be updated (KB123456)

Kind regards

Comment: Why aren't you using the WSUS-services for handling what patches to deploy?

Comment: Because my manager asked me to.
WSUS is blocked in our server in purpose, I don't know if its just to improve my script writing skills or there is really something else behind this, because its was like that even before I started work here

Comment: Beside as far as I know you don't have an option to schedule updates less than once a weak at WSUS.
We need to do it once in two weeks

Comment: But the patches are only released from MS once a month...

Comment: We don't want to install them immediately, but wait 2 weeks from release in case there are problems with the patch/update.
Of Course if there is an important patch that we need to install immediately we're pushing it manually.